# Get requireJS module URL

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In RequireJS, we can report error with this:

```
requirejs.onError = function (err) {
    console.log("requirejs: "+err.requireType+" Modules:"+ err.requireModules+" Message:"+err);
    if (err.requireType === 'timeout') {
        console.log('requirejs modules timeout: ' + err.requireModules);
    }else if(err.requireType === 'scripterror') {
        alert("I want to show error module URL here");
    }
};
```

From my understanding, we can get the error type, and module name. But how can I get the module URL that run into error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the module URL by using following line of code

```
var moduleURL = err.originalError.srcElement.src;
```